# How can I show that the hypothesis $\mu = \mu_0$ is true exactly if $\mathbf a'\mu = \mathbf a'\mu_0$ for all vectors $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^p$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How can I show that the hypothesis $\mu = \mu_0$ is true exactly if $\mathbf a'\mu = \mathbf a'\mu_0$  for all vectors $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that $A \implies B \iff B^c \implies A^c$.

You can prove your statement by contrapositive: suppose $\mu \neq \mu_0$, then it is enough to show that there exists one $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that $a'\mu \neq a'\mu_0$.

Let $p=2$ and let $\mu = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \cr -2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mu_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \cr -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $a'\mu = 2(a_1-a_2)$ and $a'\mu_0 = (a_1-a_2)$, which are not equal for any $a_1 \neq a_2$.